# are elements of an array in a set?

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy
data = numpy.random.randint(0, 10, (6,8))
test = set(numpy.random.randint(0, 10, 5))
```

I want an expression whose value is a Boolean array, with the same shape of `data` (or, at least, can be reshaped to the same shape), that tells me if the corresponding term in `data` is in `set`.

E.g., if I want to know which elements of `data` are strictly less than `6`, I can use a single *vectorized* expression,

```
a = data < 6
```

that computes a `6x8` boolean ndarray.  On the contrary, when I try an apparently equivalent boolean expression

```
b = data in test
```

what I get is an exception:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

---

#### Addendum — benmarching different solutions

*Edit: the possibility #4 below gives wrong results, thanks to hpaulj
and Divakar for getting me on the right track.*

Here I compare four different possibilities,

1. What was proposed by Divakar, `np.in1d(data, np.hstack(test))`.
2. One proposal by hpaulj, `np.in1d(data, np.array(list(test)))`.
3. Another proposal by hpaulj,  `np.in1d(data, np.fromiter(test, int)).
4. <strike>What was proposed in an answer removed by its author, whose name I dont remember, `np.in1d(data, test)`.</strike>

Here it is the Ipython session, slightly edited to avoid blank lines

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: nr, nc = 100, 100
In [3]: top = 3000
In [4]: data = np.random.randint(0, top, (nr, nc))
In [5]: test = set(np.random.randint(0, top, top//3))
In [6]: %timeit np.in1d(data, np.hstack(test))
100 loops, best of 3: 5.65 ms per loop
In [7]: %timeit np.in1d(data, np.array(list(test)))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.4 ms per loop
In [8]: %timeit np.in1d(data, np.fromiter(test, int))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.33 ms per loop
```

<strike>`In [9]: %timeit np.in1d(data, test)`

`1000 loops, best of 3: 687 µs per loop`</strike>

```
In [10]: nr, nc = 1000, 1000
In [11]: top = 300000
In [12]: data = np.random.randint(0, top, (nr, nc))
In [13]: test = set(np.random.randint(0, top, top//3))
In [14]: %timeit np.in1d(data, np.hstack(test))
1 loop, best of 3: 706 ms per loop
In [15]: %timeit np.in1d(data, np.array(list(test)))
1 loop, best of 3: 269 ms per loop
In [16]: %timeit np.in1d(data, np.fromiter(test, int))
1 loop, best of 3: 274 ms per loop
```

<strike>`In [17]: %timeit np.in1d(data, test)`

`10 loops, best of 3: 67.9 ms per loop`</strike>

```
In [18]:
```

<strike>The better times are given by the (now) anonymous poster's answer.</strike>

It turns out that the anonymous poster had a good reason to remove their answer, the results being wrong!

As commented by hpaulj, in the documentation of `in1d` there is a warning against the use of a `set` as the second argument, but I'd like better an explicit failure if the computed results could be wrong.

That said, the solution using `numpy.fromiter()` has the best numbers...

Comment: The output would be of the same shape as `data` or as `set`?

Comment: What would the expected output be? `data < 6` produces a new array for example.

Comment: @Divakar Not necessarily as long as the size is the same and I can use `numpy.reshape`

Comment: @gboffi: that's not all that clear. `data in test` would produce either `True` or `False` since `set` objects are not `numpy` objects.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Tx for the edit, I put `data < 6` exactly as an example of the type of expression and the type of output that I want, and the output would be, for the particular problem, a `6x8` boolean ndarray.

Comment: @MartijnPieters `data in test` produces a `TypeError` --- I'm going to edit my question to address Divakar's comments as well yours.

Comment: @HåkenLid IThank you for your edit, but I feel I have it reverted, because I knew already why `data in set` doesn;t work before asking my question, that imho has nothing to do with the title you've put on it.

Comment: No problem. You don't need my permission to change the title back, just click edit. If possible, it's preferable that the title is in the form of a question, though.

Comment: `np.in1d(data, test)` is fastest because it doesn't check against all the members of the set, and thus gives a completely different result  than the others.

Comment: Since you haven't included my suggestion in your benchmarks, I've added a benchmark to my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming you are looking to find a boolean array to detect the presence of the `set` elements in `data` array. To do so, you can extract the elements from `set` with [`np.hstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) and then use [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to detect presence of **any** element from `set` at **each** position in `data`, giving us a boolean array of the same size as `data`. Since, `np.in1d` flattens the input before processing, so as a final step, we need to reshape the output from `np.in1d` back to its original `2D` shape. Thus, the final implementation would be -

```
np.in1d(data,np.hstack(test)).reshape(data.shape)
```

Sample run -

```
In [125]: data
Out[125]: 
array([[7, 0, 1, 8, 9, 5, 9, 1],
       [9, 7, 1, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4],
       [0, 4, 9, 6, 6, 3, 5, 9],
       [2, 2, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 2],
       [3, 4, 8, 4, 2, 1, 9, 8],
       [9, 0, 8, 1, 6, 1, 3, 5]])

In [126]: test
Out[126]: {3, 4, 6, 7, 9}

In [127]: np.in1d(data,np.hstack(test)).reshape(data.shape)
Out[127]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False,  True, False, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: You have _perfectly_ understood what I was asking, thank you. I didn't know of `in1d`: `numpy`'s namespace is a real treasure chest... For the moment, your answer is correct and there is a little extra gem hidden in `np.hstack(test)`, I'd likely approve it as soon as possible, for the while it's a +1

Comment: @gboffi Bit of guess work, but glad to finally get it right! :) Yeah I just discovered while answering this, that one can convert set to NumPy array with `np.hstack` (at least for such a set). I don't deal with sets a lot, but seems like useful stuff that one.

Comment: `hstack` is using `[np.atleast_1d(i) for i in test]` convert the set to a list of arrays.  `np.array(list(test))` or `np.fromiter(test,int)` also work.

Comment: @hpaulj In effects it is possible to call directly `np.in1d(data, test)`, as was shown in a good answer that its poster has removed. In this case (using directly a `set`, with no conversion) `numpy` has to do something behind the scenes... I'll try to benchmark and show the results.

Comment: `in1d` warns against using a `set` directly.  In your time test cases, check whether the results are the same.  I get all `False` in the direct `test` case.

Comment: Study the `np.in1d` code.  Run its code step by step on a small test case.  It will be instructive.  It uses a rather cleaver idea, involving concatenation and sorting.

Comment: @gboffi `np.in1d` expects NumPy arrays as inputs. `test` is a set, so we have to convert that to a regular NumPy array. `np.in1d(data, test)` won't give you the correct results. If you manually inspect the results for a `6x8` array, you would see. Or use `np.allclose()` between outputs for that same verification.

Answer (score 4):

The expression `a = data < 6` returns a new array because `<` is a value comparison operator.

> #### [Arithmetic, matrix multiplication, and comparison operations](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#arithmetic-matrix-multiplication-and-comparison-operations)
>
> Arithmetic and comparison operations on ndarrays are defined as
>   element-wise operations, and generally yield ndarray objects as
>   results.
>
> Each of the arithmetic operations (+, -, *, /, //, %, divmod(), ** or
>   pow(), <<, >>, &, ^, |, ~) and the comparisons (==, <, >, <=, >=, !=)
>   is equivalent to the corresponding universal function (or ufunc for
>   short) in Numpy.

Note that the `in` operator is not in this list. Probably because it works in the opposite direction to most operators.

While `a + b` is the same as `a.__add__(b)`, `a in b` works right to left `b.__contains__(a)`. In this case python tries to call `set.__contains__()`, which will only accept hashable/immutable types. Arrays are mutable, so they can't be a member of a set.

A solution to this is to use **`numpy.vectorize`** instead of `in` directly, and call any python function on each element in the array.

It's a kind of `map()` for numpy arrays.

> #### [numpy.vectorize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html#numpy-vectorize)
>
> Define a vectorized function which takes a nested sequence of objects
>   or numpy arrays as inputs and returns a numpy array as output. The
>   vectorized function evaluates pyfunc over successive tuples of the
>   input arrays like the python map function, except it uses the
>   broadcasting rules of numpy.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> data = numpy.random.randint(0, 10, (3, 3))
>>> test = set(numpy.random.randint(0, 10, 5))
>>> numpy.vectorize(test.__contains__)(data)

array([[False, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

#### Benchmarks

This approach is fast when n is large, since `set.__contains__()` is a constant time operation. ("large" means that`top` > 13000 or so)

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> nr, nc = 100, 100
>>> top = 300000
>>> data = np.random.randint(0, top, (nr, nc))
>>> test = set(np.random.randint(0, top, top//3))
>>> %timeit -n10 np.in1d(data, list(test)).reshape(data.shape)
10 loops, best of 3: 26.2 ms per loop

>>> %timeit -n10 np.in1d(data, np.hstack(test)).reshape(data.shape)
10 loops, best of 3: 374 ms per loop

>>> %timeit -n10 np.vectorize(test.__contains__)(data)
10 loops, best of 3: 3.16 ms per loop
```

However, when n is small, the other solutions are significantly faster.

Comment: is it possible to vectorize (i.e. speed up)  the 2D DFT operation expressed in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70768384/right-method-for-finding-2-d-spatial-spectrum-from-cross-spectral-densities?